# Flutter - Button to change language

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, state

- I'm going through an old tutorial and I cannot see what I am doing
  wrong.
- There are two buttons. They change to screen to desired
  language. En or Af.
- state?.setState(()  refuses to execute. This method is not running at ALL.
- I am new to localization

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

    return MaterialApp(
  
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      title: 'Flutter localization Demo',

      home: const MyHomePage(title: "This My home Page title"),
      // home: title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld),
```

- static locale placed in Stateful widget. This is where locale is set to change.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  /*
  To Change Locale of App This is where I am not winning:
   */
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
    _MyHomePageState? state =
        context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyHomePageState>();
    print('In setLocale() newlocale $newLocale');
    // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member

    state?.setState(() {
      print('setLocale() newlocale set state $newLocale'); //not printing
      state._locale = newLocale;
      print('setLocale () and changing locale state'); //not printing
    });
  }

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();

  static _MyHomePageState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyHomePageState>();
}
```

- seems like _locale variable isn't used so tried to set it to default language 'en' but flutter is still not happy.
- 2 simple buttons to click to desired language

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Locale _locale = const Locale('en');


      ),
  
// The 2 Buttons:

            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                print("English button pressed");
                setState(() {
                  MyHomePage.setLocale(context, const Locale('en'));
                });
              },         
              label: const Text('English'),
            ),
          
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Afrikaans button pressed");
                  setState(() {
                    MyHomePage.setLocale(context, const Locale('af'));
                  });
                },
                child: const Text("Afrikaans")),
```